# understanding issue with year got from localtime in perl

Tags: perl

I have seen many blogs saying the `localtime` function returns years from 1900.
But for me when I add 180 days to the current date and print it using `localtime` it's showing the proper year as 2016 instead of 116.

Example:

```
$today_date=timelocal(0,0,0,27,03,2016);
$seconds=180*60*24*60;
$date=today_date+seconds;
$new_date=localtime(date);
print strftime("%d-%m-%Y",$new_date);

Output:
24-10-2016
```

When I give input as 116 instead of 2016 as year to timelocal It still gives the output as 2016.How is this possible?

Comment: That is correct. I don't know what the `strf` function is, but that is where to check if you are looking for the place that the year gets converted to 2016.

Comment: Hi, function is strftime. However without using this function it should display year as 116 right? But it was displaying 2016 only.

Comment: What you've shown isn't valid Perl code. Please show the actual code you're using. Also, `seconds=180+(60*24*60);` is one day and 180 seconds, not 180 days.

Comment: Yes it should be $date=(180*24*60*60) + $today_date

Comment: `perl -MTime::Local -E '@y=localtime(timelocal(0,0,0,28,3,2016)+180*86400);say "@y"'`. Result: `0 0 0 25 9 116 2 298 1`

Answer (score -2):

Your sourcecode is wrong, you're missing the `$` signs in front of the variable names.

You start by calling `timelocal` from the module [Time::Local](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Time::Local) which takes the number of years since 1900 as input, but pass 2016 as year value. In the end, you pass this date back to `localtime` which is exactly the opposite function.

Try this:

```
print time;
print join(" ",localtime(time));

1461783061
1 51 20 27 3 116 3 117 1
```

You get:

- Second 1
- Minute 51
- Hour 20
- Day 27
- Zero-based month 3 which is April
- 1900-based year 116 which is 2016

My default usage of `localtime` is:

```
my @now = localtime(time);
# Convert zero-based-month to calendar month
++$now[4];
# Convert 1900-based-year to calendar year
$now[5] += 1900;
```

If all you need is a date calculation, try [Date::Calc](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date::Calc)

```
use Date::Calc qw(Today Add_Delta_Days);

print join '-', Today();
print join '-', Add_Delta_Days(Today(),1);

2016-4-27
2016-4-28
```

or [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

print DateTime->now->add(days => 1, seconds => 180);

2016-04-28T19:00:12
```

`DateTime`'s `strftime` method or `formatter` option will give you any output you want.

Comment: Can you please explain "You start by calling timelocal from the module Time::Local which takes the number of years since 1900 as input, but pass 2016 as year value. In the end, you pass this date back to localtime which is exactly the opposite function."                                                                         Why its not printing 116 instead of 2016..this is what my doubt

Comment: [The year input in `timelocal` is DWIM.](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local#Year-Value-Interpretation), so it doesn't always treat the year argument as years since 1900.

Comment: @Sebastian [`timelocal` treats year values > 999 as the actual year, not as the offset from 1900.](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Local#Year-Value-Interpretation)

Comment: Sorry, never used it this way.

Comment: @mob and @ ThisSuitIsBlackNot..according to you whatever year 2016 i am passing to timelocal function is correct right?.[I know for month we need to decrease it by 1.]